# why jQueryUi dialog box doesn't work on IE9

Tags: jquery-ui, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

i have some problem with ie9 and jquery ui but still cant find solution please help me

When i click Detail dialog must be open and it works on ie7,ie8,FF,Chrome but don't in ie9

```
$(function() {
    var popup = $("#popup"),
        allFields = $([]).add(popup);

    $("#dialog-form").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 800,
        width: 1200,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {},
        close: function() {
            allFields.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
        }
    });
});

function dialogOpen(id) {
    $('#dialog-form').dialog('open');
}

<div id="pageopen" onclick="dialogOpen('dialog-form')">
    <div id="detail" style="text-decoration:underline;">Detail</div>
</div>

<div id="dialog-form" title="Detail"></div>
```

Comment: is there any error in console

Comment: Yes this is error = "cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'"

Comment: I fixed some errors in your code (maybe copy/paste errors ?) and test it on IE9 with success (as other IE versions and other browsers). How are you testing on IE9 ? using debug console (F12) and changing mod ?

Comment: Yes i use debug console F12 and change mode

Comment: solved the problem this is about IE9 bug unfortunatelly... Here how i solved problem i just use var dialog and use it like this var dialog; $(document).ready(function() { dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({ } }); }); function dialogOpen(pid) { dialog.dialog('open'); } and it works.. Thank you for helps

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in document.ready. You trying to open the dialog before it is being created.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#dialog-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 800,
    width: 1200,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {},
    close: function() {
        allFields.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Yeah i tried that but debugger doesnt enter the inside $("#dialog-form").dialog code

Comment: I solved the problem this is about IE9 bug unfortunatelly...

Here how i solved problem i just use var dialog and use it like this
  var dialog;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
            }
        });
    });

   function dialogOpen(pid) { 
    dialog.dialog('open');
}
and it works..

Thank you for helps